# jQuery: how to place a highlight to cover another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to create a transparent highlight to cover a particular DOM element.

My highlight will occasionally be switched from one element to another.

The basic implementation is easy: create an empty `<div class='highlight'/>` with css attributes for background-color and opacity.

But having it follow another element seems hard, because the highlighted element could move or resize or show or hide, and I'm not sure how to have the highlight follow it.

There must be someone who's done this before -- Firebug seems to have the effect I want, but I don't know how to delve into the Firebug source code + find the relevant piece.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't use the [jQuery highlight effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight)?

Comment: hmm, I don't want the pulsing aspect of it, I just want a plain highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Simple HTML element at the top of your DOM:

```
<div id="highlighter" class="highlight"></div>
```

Style it with abstracted CSS:

```
div {
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    position:relative;
}
#highlighter {
    display:none;
    border:none;
}
.highlight {
    z-index:999999;
    background-color:yellow;
    opacity:.5;
    -moz-opacity:.5;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

The JQuery is a little more complicated if you want the highlighter to tag along with your animated divs:

```
$('div').not('.highlight').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.find('.highlight').length > 0) {
        $this.find('.highlight').remove();
    } else {
        $('#highlighter').clone().appendTo($this).
        width($this.width()).
        height($this.height()).
        css({
            'top': '0px',
            'left': '0px'
        }).
        show();
    }
});


(function morph(){

    $('div').not('.highlight').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({
            'top'  : someVal + 'px',
            'left' : someVal + 'px',
            'width': someVal + 'px',
            'left' : someVal + 'px',
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function(){
               // Here we tell the highlighter to sync up with the morphed parent.
               $this.find('.highlight').width($this.width()).height($this.height());
            },
            complete: morph
        });
    });
}());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/7t4jT/

Comment: well, `insertAfter()` helps me with one aspect of it, but how does that deal with elements that can move/scroll/show/hide/resize? That's the problem I'm trying to solve.